# npm run test task in VSCode suddenly injecting with yarn

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, task

I run my backend tests with `npm run test:backend` from the root of my project, suddenly as of today the task command is injecting yarn into the command

```
 Executing task: yarn run test:backend 

/bin/bash: yarn: command not found
```

When I run `npm run test:backend` from the integrated terminal everything runs fine, but the "Run Task" has suddenly started requiring yarn.

This must have been some autoupdate by VSCode.

How can I get back to running my tasks with npm run

my tasks.json has this

```
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "test:backend",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm test:backend",
            "detail": "backend tests",
            "group": "build"
        },
```

Comment: show you package.json. I wonder if this is a case of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170101. Did you recently add a `workspaces` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to VSCode settings and searched "Use Yarn" and I set the package manager as npm

VSCode Setting ID: npm.packageManager

Comment: my question is how this happened to you in the first place. Did you change it to "Yarn" accidentally in the past? Did something bug out and do it without your initially noticing? The latter would do well with more follow up with maintainers.

Comment: I did not change any settings myself. It was on "Auto". Maybe "Auto" was npm, but now it's yarn, I don't know.